# Adding a folder to existing SVN

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN folder that is located on the C drive.

Anyway, I want to add my web project folder into it, which is located in my inetpub folder. How can I add a new folder into an existing repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should help, basically you can you tortise svn context menu for all the things you may need
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-add.html

Comment: Instead of just pointing to the documentation, please answer the question here and provide the link as additional information.

Comment: Thanks, add is missing when I right click on the folder. I have read that I need to move the folder and put inside the directory, but that is inconvienient as it means I will have to do that all the time?

Comment: The good practice is to keep working project and it sources in separate locations, this means that you should have the source code in your SVN folder and when you are finishing with coding just copy result to your release (interpub) folder. But if you want keep all in one place you should check out your sources to the inetpub folder, after that you can add your folder and check in back